# Proper use of z-index on DnD

Tags: javascript, html, css, click, z-index

I am trying implement a Drag & Drop using https://github.com/gardiner/draganddrop but it seems I am stocked with the library not [letting me click on the component as show in the Codeply](https://www.codeply.com/go/VYSeSB23Ul) even with defining z-index.

Please I will appreciate your help on fixing the issue. The mean issue is that I cannot type in the **Input** text nor **Select** from the dropdown list. I believe this is an issue with CSS z-index.

Comment: THis is an unclear question, you should add some of the code thats causing you issues or explain exactly what the issue is and how you want it resolved. Both links orovide examples, but no clarity on your goal.

Comment: @somethinghere I added little more detail but full code is at https://www.codeply.com/go/VYSeSB23Ul